# How does $\text{span}\left\{X_2, X_3\right\}\cap S^2$ look like and where is it on the sphere?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

Consider the linear 3-dim. ODE system
$$
\dot{\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\-f'(u_1) & -c & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}}_{=:A}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $f'(u_1)<0, c>0$ and $U_1=(u_1,v_1,w_1)$ is some point we linearized at.

Then, $A$ has the following three eigenvalues:

$$
\lambda_1=-\frac{c}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4}-f'(u_1)},~~\lambda_2=0,~~~\lambda_3=-\frac{c}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{4}-f'(u_1)}.
$$

$\lambda_1$ is positive, $\lambda_3$ is negative.

Hence, in terms of stability theory, the ODE has two stable subspaces (namely the stable subset that is spanned by the eigenvector $X_3$ belonging to $\lambda_3$ and the centre subspace which is spanned by the eigenvector $X_2$ belonging to $\lambda_2$) and one unstable subspace (spanned by the eigenvector $X_1$ belonging to $\lambda_1$).

When I now project the ODE onto the sphere $S^2$, I get a new ODE which acts on the sphere (more precisely: a new ODE on the projective space by identifying opposite points on the sphere). And it follows that the unstable subspace of the original ODE becomes two attracting points for the ODE on the sphere (the red point in the picture below and its opposite point) and the stable subspace of the original ODE becomes two repelling points (the blue point in the picture and its opposite point) for the ODE on the sphere.

The green point is a saddle point (and also its opposite point) which arises from the centre subspace of the original ODE.

**My questions now are the following ones:**

(1.) Where on the picture do we see $\text{span}\left\{X_1\right\}\cap S^2$? I guess this is nothing else but the red point (and its opposite point).

(2.) Where on the picture do we see $C:=\text{span}\left\{X_2,X_3\right\}\cap S^2$?

(3.) Somebody told me that "inside $C$" we have that $\text{span}\left\{X_1\right\}\cap S^2$ is attracting. But, frankly speaking, I have no idea what may be meant by *inside $C$*. What may be meant by *inside $C$*? Where is *inside $C$* on the picture?

Maybe you can help me. I would be very thankful for any help. Sorry for too much text but I had to describe my problem a bit more detailed.

Kind regards!

[image: attracting point (red), repelling point (blue) and saddle point (green) of the dynamics on the sphere - note that the opposite points on the sphere are also attracting, repelling and saddle, respectively.]

Comment: It is not clear to me what is the "projection of the ODE on the sphere" ? Do you mean that you first take the canonical projection $\pi:(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,y,0)$ and second use a smooth diffeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\times{0}\simeq\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^2$ to go to the sphere ?

Comment: The text says: Since it is linear, it induces an ODE on the projective space $P^2$ by identifying opposite points on the sphere. Sorry, that's all I can add. In fact, I have problems to understand that, too.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}^2$ is obtained by quotienting $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus {{0}}$ by the relation $\sim$ defined by : $D_1\sim D_2$ iff $D_1//D_2$ for all lines $D_1,D_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now we can identifies the elements of $\mathbb{P}^2$ as points on the unit sphere : each point corresponds to one and only one line passing through $0$ and intersecting the sphere at this point ; so a point of $\mathbb{P}^2$ is the set of point of $\mathbb{R}^3$ lying on the only line intersecting the unit sphere at this point. But then, what is an ODE ? A norm ? What means differentiability on $\mathbb{P}^2$ ?

Comment: I thought of something like $s(t)=\frac{x(t)}{\lvert x(t)\rvert}$.

Comment: $x$ does not exist any more after the quotient. We can induce a topology on $\mathbb{P}^2$ by asking that the canonical projections $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus {0}\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^2$ are continuous. But it is not clear that this topology is metrizable and if it induces a norm on $\mathbb{P}^2$. But anyway, it seems that your questions reduced to identify the image of the above projection of the stable/unstable spaces on $\mathbb{P}^2$ (you can identify each point as a point on the sphere, the north point being the infinity of $\mathbb{P}^2$).

Comment: Besides the understanding of the projection, my question is indeed where to find the projected invariant spaces I have mentioned and "inside C".

Comment: If $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\setminus{0}$ is any vector, then its corresponding homogen coordinates are $[kx,ky,kz]$ with $k\in\mathbb{R}$ (it is the set of all points on the line passing through $(x,y,z)$ and $0$). Now you want to be on the sphere, so you put $k=1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. So what you have to do is finding the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues you've computed, and then project them on the sphere. A line becomes a point and a plane becomes the great circle on the sphere passing through the two projections of two vectors spanning this plane. All modulo opposite points.

Comment: The fact that the intersection of a sphere and a plane passing through the origin of this sphere is a great circle on the sphere is a well known result of differential geometry : it is a geodesic of the sphere.

Comment: So C is the longitude that on which the two blue and two green points are?

Comment: $X_3$ spans the stable subspace so I thought that it was the red point instead ? In that case, $C$ would be the longitude on which the two red and the two green points are (if I misread your notations, so your answer is correct - $C$ is anyway a longitude as the projection of a plane passing through $0$).

Comment: I think that the stable subspace resp. the eigenvector $X_3$ that spans it becomes two repelling points of the "new" ODE on the sphere which I made blue. And the unstable subspace (the spanning eigenvector) becomes two attractive points which colored red.

Comment: The problem is still what is an ODE on the sphere ? We can talk about ODEs and PDEs on manifolds by seeing them in $\mathbb{R}^n$ thanks to smooth diffeomorphisms. The authors of your text are not clear on what they mean by "projection on the sphere of the ODE" : if they say that you project the subspaces on the sphere, then $C$ is a longitude passing through the two pairs of points representing the projection of the line spanned by $X_2$ and $X_3$ as we discussed ; if not, then there is a lack of details to me... This is the problem with some authors : they aren't precise...